# Layout inside include always null inside adapter

Tags: android

I am showing a list of items in a recycler view.
The item_layout.xml has an include which its parent is a ContraintLayout and it has some elements inside which i can point to them easily by view.elementID

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout...>

...

      <include
        android:id="@+id/incNumberPicker"
        layout="@layout/number_picker"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_big"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lblFamily"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />


...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I can get the reference of the include layout but not on the parent layout of this include.
and I tried...

```
    private val incNumberPicker =  view.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.incNumberPicker) (not null)
    private val bgNumberPicker = view.bgNumberPicker (null)
    private val bgNumberPicker =  incNumberPicker.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.bgNumberPicker) (null)
    private val bgNumberPicker = view.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.bgNumberPicker)(null)
```

This is my include layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/bgNumberPicker"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/number_picker_bg">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNumber"
        style="@style/et_number_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_normal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_normal"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnAdd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnRemove"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This parent constraint has a background which I want to change the color depending on the state, so I want to enadle/disable this constraintlayout. the thing is I can point the rest of the elements very easily with a normal view.etNumber but not to the parent constraint.

UPDATE trace error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: dev.game.jupiter, PID: 29108
java.lang.IllegalStateException: bgNumberPicker must not be null
    at es.game.jupiter.ui.inventory.productsCounter.InventoriedProductAdapter$InventoriedProductViewHolder.setLocationPickerEditable(InventoriedProductAdapter.kt:95)
    at es.game.jupiter.ui.inventory.productsCounter.InventoriedProductAdapter$InventoriedProductViewHolder.hideShowOptions(InventoriedProductAdapter.kt:85)
    at es.game.jupiter.ui.inventory.productsCounter.InventoriedProductAdapter$InventoriedProductViewHolder$3.onClick(InventoriedProductAdapter.kt:65)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5205)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please post the error you're getting here. That will make us understand your question better.

Comment: updated question. The error is the same with any of the three ways I tried to get the reference before.

Comment: Your 'view' is 'item_layout.xml', which does not have the 'id = bgNumberPicker', and you are using 'findViewById' inside 'item_layout.xml'.

Comment: item_layout has layout/number_picker as include and I can get reference of EditText inside but not of the parent?